# What Android Device Should I Get to Develop My Android App?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I'm going to be writing my Android app soon, and thinking about buying a solid android device to develop on and play with. My question is for you guys, assuming you wanted to develop and test your app on an Adroid device, what would you recommend?

Samsung Galaxy looks promising, but I know choosing a good dev phone is one of those things you definitely need to choose wisely on. The Android device landscape seems to be broadening every day, so it'd be good to hear about the latest devices for developing. Perhaps I could just get a cheap clunker and it won't make a difference?

I'm sort of a nerd, so if the device is pricey, but has some cool features that others don't, then I'd still consider it. However, I don't want to waste too much money on features that I may not need (or that may distract me ;)), like HD video, although it looks like a lot of phones have HD support anyways.

Tablets seem a bit much, but I'm still open to it... if you're loving your Android tablet *for developing*, let me know about it. I could see some benefits like being sure my app will run on Android tablets and different resolutions.

Any caveats I should be worried about? I have a buddy who was developing Android when it first came out and I remember him complaining that he could never update his device, since the updates were always restricted for some reason. Is that still the case?

If you can speak to any of these points, I'd be happy to hear them.

Also concerned about using the location based stuff, like gps, will I need a contract?

I'll be developing on my Macbook Air OSX, if you have any additional input as far as devices go, and using a Mac, that would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: One criteria is popularity.  If you want the best possible user experience, you want to test with a device similar to one many of your users will have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Good because it is a phone that is supported directly from Google.

Samsung Galaxy S2, it just has all the features you need

One of those two for spec heavy phones, but you also need a cheaper not so good phone so you can get both ends of the device range, so get something like a IDEOS as well.

All you need to remember is that there is never going to be just one type of device being used, there are hundreds, if you have a phone thats close to the bottom and your app works almost as well as a phone as the top it will be good, because you will be able to catch the whole range of customers.

Also for location based things all you need to do is put permissions in the android manifest and it should be good, users are notified about these when they download the application

Mac can be good for development, its supported by Android as well so I dont think you will have a problem, when I went to the Android devs lab it seemed to be that all the Google guys had macs anyway

Answer (score 4):

You should develop against the Android 4 platform, but during the course of development, you will figure out which APIs you are using. The level of APIs you are using determines which minimal OS you will support. There's 2 manifest settings in play here: target API (15 aka ICS), and minimal API (depends on what you use).

To get a good mix of API support and broad coverage in the consumer market (using the dashboard that @Basic pointed to), I tend to point people at API level 8, which is Android 2.2 (aka Froyo). You'll hit roughly 93% of people out there and you'll get the APIs you need for most development. If you know you need newer APIs, by all means use them. The world will catch up, it may just take some time.

I typically point people to get a Nexus phone or XOOM tablet. You need the reference design so you can stay on top of the official releases from Google as quickly as they come out. The AOSP builds are important to follow, but they aren't the only game in town. After that, if you want to be serious about it, you should pick up one phone each from the major OEMs so you can deal with the differences in the customized platforms (Sense, Blur, Touchwiz, etc.)

Disclaimer: I work for Motorola. MOTODEV Studio is my teams' product (thanks Basic!)

Comment: Small world! It should be me thanking you though - very handy IDE, thank you

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to support. There's a whole spectrum from the HTC Wildfire up to Galaxy S2 / HTC One.

What versions of Android are you going to target? [Some people are *still* on 1.5](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)!

Regarding updates: Google releases updates at their own speed. The problem is that before that update reaches a given device, the carrier usually customises it to include branding, mandatory aspps, etc... Which can take an indeterminate length of time or may not happen at all. This was one huge benefit of the Nexus One - it wasn't branded so updates were available as soon as they were released.

Regarding Development: [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is available for almost every platform and is a great starting place. [MOTODev Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/) is based on eclipse and is excellent as it comes with templates, pre-configured emulators, etc...

Location Services: Android uses 3 approaches to get your location: GPS (Works poorly indoors, can be slow to get a fix, quite a battery hog), Wifi (Google have mapped the location of a lot of wifi networks - thus if it can see a known wifi network, it knows roughly where it is) and finally network (It knows the location of the cell tower(s) your phone is talking to).

None of the above needs a contract but Wifi requires an internet connection (to perform the lookup) and Network obviously requires your phone to be in range of and allowed to talk to a cell tower - which usually just means getting a sim for a network which covers your area.

Note that when getting location on the device, you can opt to have coarse of fine-grained location information. Coarse doesn't fire up the GPS (They also require different permissions)

See [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) for more info about location

Comment: Yeah thats true, but mainly people are on 2.3.3, yeah you can target 1.5 if you wanted to but its only 0.3% of the market

Comment: @SmartLemon I know - I was just making the point that if you're considering phones, you should also consider OS version/capabilities

Comment: Yeah, thats true, I think most things have been back ported to 1.6 which is good, when ever you are developing applications, until like 99% of the market is above 3.0 then use the support packages instead of the actual APIs

Comment: @SmartLemon I've still got my old 1.6 T-Mobile G1 kicking around but it's not really viable for anyt vaguely modern apps. I personally would target 2.3 for new development (Not least because my Desire HD is 2.3.3)

Comment: ok, so this issue looks more serious than I realized. Kinda reminds me of developing for Flash, targeting certain Flash Player versions... but maybe even more complicated. My first thought was to dev it out in Android 4, just to get a feel for it and get excited about the *newness*, then go backwards from there once I get a good prototype... you're totally right though, I should probably target a certain version if I want the app to be adopted. great info, totally appreciated.

Comment: I think you should have a phone at the top and the bottom, develop for the bottom but also have a nice one to more or less build on, they are good investments, I have a Samsung 10.1 tab and that was quite good, but I also have a IDEOS, IDEOS X3, and a Motorola Defy, all quite different. And it works out a dream

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend the Toshiba Thrive 10.1 Inch Android Tablet.

It has:

1 GHz Nvidia Tegra

1 GB RAM

Full Size USB Port

Full Size SD Card Slot

Full Size HDMI Port

Mini USB Port

Can be upgraded from Android 3.1 to 3.2 or 4.0

And it usually only costs about $200-250 depending on how much memory you want.